# Selecting text from iframe with mouse and showing selection in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know how to select a text with the mouse and show that selection in a div. But how can I do the same thing when I have an iframe which shows a page on the same domain.

Can't figure it out. I have implemented the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448701/javascript-highlight-select-word-under-mouse-pointer).

Any ideas which could help me out or links to other SO questions that addressed this?

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php) how to get the references to `window` and `document` for the `iframe` (or vice versa, the references to the main document from inside the `iframe`); from there, it should be easy to do anything you're currently doing in the main document.

Comment: awesome! Worked like a charm :)