# How can I get a word that is under a double tap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have some text inside a < p > element, and need to find the word that was double tapped.

I am using  a double tap jquery plugin (https://gist.github.com/attenzione/7098476) which works great on detecting the event, but I don't know how to get the word that is under it.

How can I get it?

---

Added what I have so far:

```
$("p").on('doubletap',function(event){
alert ("double tap"); // event is working
var sel = (document.selection && document.selection.createRange().text) || (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().toString());
alert ("sel "+sel); //<-- not working
});
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only get the word you double tapped on, you should use `span` tags around each word. That way you add the double tap event listener on `p > span` and you can fetch the word using `$(clickedElement).text();`.

**EDIT: Add example code**
based on code given on Fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $("#yourTextContainer").text().split(' ');
    $("#yourTextContainer").html("");

    $.each(words, function(i,val) {
        // wrap each word in a span tag 
        $('<span/>').text(val +" ").appendTo("#yourTextContainer");
    });

    $("#yourTextContainer span").dblclick(function(event) {
        var res = $(this).text();
        console.log ("sel "+res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one similar question for selecting word on single click.
[Use the mouse to select only one word in text jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180070/use-the-mouse-to-select-only-one-word-in-text-jquery)

You can change the event from click to `dbclick` like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/EHCN6/92/

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var words = $("#yourTextContainer").text().split(' ');
    $("#yourTextContainer").html("");

    $.each(words, function (i, val)
    {
        //wrap each word in a span tag 
        $('<span/>').text(val + " ").appendTo("#yourTextContainer");
    });

    $("#yourTextContainer span").live("dbclick", function (event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        SelectText($(this));
    });
});

function SelectText(element)
{
    var doc = document,
            text = element.get(0),
            range,
            selection;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange)
    {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (window.getSelection)
    {
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Returned the selected text.
Check the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/mzx6zL65/2/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not even able to get this one work on desktop. (getting undeifned as result, sel = SelectText($(this));)

Comment: Can you update your question and show the code how you use it?

Comment: @tejashsoni111 why so complex code when you just need to return .text() of the double clicked element? (updated my answer to show what I mean)

Comment: @fran35 by mistake I used the wrong approach for returning the selected value that day. but I have updated my fiddle : [https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/mzx6zL65/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/mzx6zL65/2/) . I would not be able to explain you why to use `selection` or `range` objects this documentation may help you to understand : [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). and [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

Comment: Also if you feel that you don't need that code then you can change it as per your requirement.