# How to get the word on which a click was made in javascript

Tags: javascript

can we get the word on which a right click was made and x,y coordinates of that word ?
i tried:
    `document.onclick=getTextOnClick;`

```
function getTextOnClick(e)
{
    console.log(e);
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection();
            console.log(">>>"+txt);
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        // FireFox 
        txt = document.getSelection();
            console.log(txt);
    } else if (document.selection) {
        // IE 6/7 
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
            console.log(txt);
    }
}
```

Now this code works if i select some text, but can i get the same when i just eight click or click on certain word ? And event object is giving me coordinates of click. can i get coordinates of the word on which the click was made ? Plz help

Comment: If somebody helps, are you going to accept an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the text under the mouse pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183335/getting-the-text-under-the-mouse-pointer)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: yes i will accept it as answer. But only when I try it and it works ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with pure JavaScript, assuming your container contain "simple" words only:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("Container");
    var rawHTML = oDiv.innerHTML;
    var arrWords = rawHTML.split(" ");
    oDiv.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrWords.length; i++) {
        var curWord = arrWords[i];
        var curSpan = document.createElement("span");
        curSpan.innerHTML = curWord;
        if (i < (arrWords.length - 1))
            curSpan.innerHTML += " ";
        curSpan.onclick = WordClicked;
        curSpan.oncontextmenu = WordClicked;
        oDiv.appendChild(curSpan);
    }
};

function WordClicked() {
    var word = this.innerHTML;
    alert("You clicked: " + word);
    return false;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/TDLPL/) - handles both left and right click.

Comment: You could add a *word of caution* for why it might not be the best idea to directly override `window.onload` (or in general, any event-handler) ... (ref: [addEventListener / attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener))

Comment: @Yoshi valid point, but I prefer to avoid complicated stuff as much as possible - and this case look simple enough.

Comment: If wrapping every word in a span is a solution, it is vastly more efficient (and accurate) to do it on the server rather than at the client. Also, it would be far safer to use DOM text nodes rather than innerHTML since the assumption here is that there is no markup inside the "Container" element. Finally, it only requires one listener on a parent element, not on every span.

Comment: @RobG about server side, no idea what's used here - and unless it's thousands of words, efficiency won't be a problem. Regarding your other points they're correct but again - as long as we're dealing with ordinary text which isn't very long it should be just fine.

Comment: but if my document has a lot of text content, won't the creation of so many spans slow it down ?

Comment: Yes in such case you can try and optimize per RobG suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

One way that comes to mind is putting each word in a span of its own. Apart from that, I think it will be difficult to find a solution that runs consistently on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Thy this ?

Text ->

```
<div id="foo">Hello I am a text. I have no clue why I am here or 
what I am good for, but I have QUOTES and other things I can offer.</div>
```

jQuery ->

```
$('#foo').contents().each(function(_, node) {
    var nodelist = node.textContent.split(/\s/).map(function( word ) {
        return $('<span>', {
            text: word + ' ',
            click: function() {
                alert( $(this).text() );
            }
        }).get(0);
    });

    $('#foo').empty().append(nodelist);
});
```

Demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/qLuEF/